# How to set the "Location Services -> Authorization Status(Application)" to "Never" by default

Tags: ios

If the location services `authorization status` is `KCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, then How to set it to `KCLAuthorizationStatusNever` ?

Comment: You don't. If it is not determined, you ask the user to choose.

Comment: Could you please advise me with the URL Strings for opening the location services of particular application in both iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: Start by reading the docs for `CLLocationManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If status is kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined then you can ask from user to get permission like this.

```
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

and here is the list of status codes

> 1-kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined //User hasn’t yet been asked to authorize location updates
>
> 2-kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted //User has location services turned off in Settings (Parental Restrictions)
>
> 3-kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied //User has been asked for authorization and tapped “No” (or turned off location in Settings)
>
> 4-kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized //User has been asked for authorization and tapped “Yes” on iOS 7 and lower.
>
> 5-kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways = kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
>
> //User authorized background use.
>
> 6-kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse
>
> //User has authorized use only when the app is in the foreground.